# How to select default select option based on option value not index while using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have options arriving in AJAX request. I had no success with setting

`$("#environment").val("SWTEST 051t:8083");`

in `success` callback function in `$http.get`. Can I select default option by **VALUE** not index after it was loaded by `get`?

```
ng-init="environment.name = environment.name || options[0].value" ng-model="environment.name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `environment.name` model, try to set its value in success callback:

```
$scope.environment.name = "SWTEST 051t:8083";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a JQuery solution:

```
    thevalue="SWTEST 051t:8083";
    $('#environment option').filter(
function(i, e) 
    {
 return $(e).val() ==thevalue}
).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

If you had this code it would work:

```
  <select id="environment">
        <option>select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>        
    </select>
```

Example working:

http://jsfiddle.net/wteopnv6/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should watch `options` change by $watch method

```
$scope.$watch("options", function (){
    $scope.environment.name = $scope.options[0].value;
});
```